# Import always undefined when installing self-authored library through npm

Tags: javascript

I am authoring a small JS library for the first time and I have some problems getting imports to work when using the library.

The library structure is this:

```
.
├── src
│   ├── Element.js
└── index.js
```

Element.js

```
function Element() {
    console.log('I am Element');
}

export default Element;
```

index.js

```
export { Element } from './src/Element';
```

Now when installing the library through `npm` and importing it, the import is `undefined`. Like this:

```
import { Element } from 'my-lib';
console.log(Element); // undefined
```

I guess there is an error somewhere, but I can't find it! Can you spot any error?

Comment: @KobyDouek Just tried it, same error.

Comment: @KobyDouek Nope, also no build error, but `Element` is `undefined`.

Comment: @KobyDouek Error in console `Element is not a function`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your error can be solved one of two ways; by changing `Element.js` or by changing the other two scripts:

`Element.js`:

```
...
export Element;
```

In this case, then the named imports will correctly reference your function.

`index.js`:

```
export Element from './src/Element';
...
```

```
import Element from 'my-lib';
```

In this case, you're exporting/importing the default namespace of `Element.js` rather than a named one.

The relevant documentation for this syntax can be found at [MDN `import`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import) and [MDN `export`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/export), and if I may offer some advice, you really should write a test script that confirms your library is working properly, and then attach it to your `package.json` like this:

```
"scripts": {
  "prepublish": "npm test",
  "test": "gulp test",
  ...
}
```

Or however you want to execute it, whether it be [`mocha`](https://mochajs.org/), etc. Doing this will prevent your library from publishing if one of your tests in the test script fails.